# Get SQL print message into a variable with ExecuteNonQuery() in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have this simple Powershell script that outputs the message "Hello World!" from SQL PRINT command:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "Server=<server>;Database=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) Write-Host $event.Message};
$conn.add_InfoMessage($handler);
$conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
$conn.Open();
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand();
$cmd.CommandTimeout=0
$cmd.CommandText = "PRINT 'Hello World!'";
$res = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$conn.Close();
```

I need to catch and parse this print output. How can I put it into a variable (in addition to just printing it out)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign the value of `$event.Message` to the global variable `$global:msg` (or other name starting with `$global:`). Then this variable will be reachable outside of the event handler scope:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "Server=<server name>;Database=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
$global:msg = ""
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $event) 
    $global:msg = $event.Message
    Write-Host $global:msg
};
$conn.add_InfoMessage($handler);
$conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true
$conn.Open();
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand();
$cmd.CommandTimeout=0
$cmd.CommandText = "PRINT 'Hello World!'";
$res = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$conn.Close();
Write-Host "The event handler message '$global:msg' is inside of the global variable!"
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest reversing order: putting in a variable first, then printing it out:

```
$message = 'Hello World!'

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "Server=<server>;Database=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) Write-Host $event.Message};
$conn.add_InfoMessage($handler);
$conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
$conn.Open();
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand();
$cmd.CommandTimeout=0
$cmd.CommandText = "PRINT $message";
$res = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$conn.Close();
```

Comment: This will not work as I don't know what text of the output will be.